# How to configure opentelemetry collector to talk to an exporter trhu a proxy

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have a kubernetes cluster where the access to internet needs to happen trhu a proxy.

However I have not been able to find how can I configure an exporter using a proxy.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured.
In the Open Telemetry deployment yaml file, in the env part, you need to add something like:

```
            - name: https_proxy
              value: http://your_proxy_hostname:your_proxy_port
```